# How to auto deploy in azure with git using terraform

Tags: git, azure, github, terraform

I am trying to write terraform script for auto deployment  in azure with git. Which means if I make any changes in Git it should auto deploy in azure. I am writing the terraform code for the same.
I tried below code

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "gitex" {
  name     = "Git-source"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "gitplan" {
  name                = "Git-appservice-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "gitapp" {
  name                = "Git-appservice"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.gitplan.id

  site_config {
    always_on = true
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = "1"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "gitvnet" {
  name                = "Git-vnet1"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "gitsnet" {
  name                 = "Git-snet1"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.gitvnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "delegationapp2"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "gitappplan" {
  name                = "Git-linux-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "linapp" {
  name                = "Git-linapp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.gitex.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.gitappplan.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.gitappplan.id

  site_config {

  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "gitswift" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.gitapp.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.gitsnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "gitsrcctrl" {
  app_id   = azurerm_linux_web_app.linapp.id
  repo_url = "https://github.com/username/repo"
  branch   = "master"
}
```

I got the following error

> Error: creating Source Control configuration for Web App: (Site Name "Git-linapp" / Resource Group "Git-source"): web.AppsClient#UpdateSourceControl: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="NotFound" Message="Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub." Details=[{"Message":"Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub."},{"Code":"NotFound"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"NotFound","ExtendedCode":"51004","Message":"Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub.","MessageTemplate":"Cannot find {0} with name {1}.","Parameters":["SourceControlToken","GitHub"]}}]

I need help with the code and also any changes to be doe on Git? Like adding Oauth authorized apps.
Would be helpful If I get the step by step process and the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you run that code? Is that a GitHub action or something else?

Comment: @JimRedmond
I ran the above terraform code in command prompt by the below commands
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to write terraform script for auto deployment in azure with git. Which means if I make any changes in Git it should auto deploy in azure. I am writing the terraform code for the same.

If you want to automatically deploy/update Azure resources whenever you make changes to the code, you can use **GitHub Actions** for deployment.

Follow the steps below to deploy resources to Azure using `GitHub Actions`.

1. Create a service principal in azure portal.

[image]

2. After creating a `Service Principal`, create a secret.

[image]

> Note: Please make a note of the Client_ID, Tenant_ID, Client_Secret, and Subscription_ID.

4. Assign a role to the created Service Principal at the subscription level (e.g.Contributor)
5. Navigate to your Git repository or create a new repository.
6. Configure a sample workflow as shown below, save the file as **Terraform.yaml**, and then commit the file."

[image]

Add the below code in `Terraform.yaml` and commit the file.

```
name: 'Terraform'
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:
 
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
 
    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
 
    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
    - name: 'Terraform Format'
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
        tf_actions_version: 0.14.8
        tf_actions_subcommand: 'fmt'
        tf_actions_working_dir: "./terraform"
         
    - name: 'Terraform Init'
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
        tf_actions_version: 0.14.8
        tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
        tf_actions_working_dir: "./terraform"
 
    - name: 'Terraform Validate'
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
        tf_actions_version: 0.14.8
        tf_actions_subcommand: 'validate'
        tf_actions_working_dir: "./terraform"
         
    - name: 'Terraform Plan'
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
        tf_actions_version: 0.14.8
        tf_actions_subcommand: 'plan'
        tf_actions_working_dir: "./terraform"
 
    - name: Terraform Apply
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
        tf_actions_version: 0.14.8
        tf_actions_subcommand: 'apply'
        tf_actions_working_dir: "./terraform"
```

Terraform config file main. tf

Add the following backend configuration to your Terraform config file for storing the **.tfstate** file in a storage account

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "Storage_Accounr_RG_name"
    storage_account_name = "storage_account-namr"
    container_name       = "container_name"
    key                  = "prod.tfstate" #the state file will be stored in Storage account.
    access_key = "Storage_accounr_Access_key"
    
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Check the [Terraform registry](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm) for storing the backend configurations in a storage account

7. Add README.md file in to same directory.
8. Add the **Client_id**, **Tenant_Id**, **Secret_Id**, and **Subscription_ID** to your **Git** repository by navigating to **Git settings > Security > Secrets and variables > Actions**

[image]
9. Clone the repository to local using git clone command

```
 Git clone "git reposotiroy url"
```

[image]

10. Once clone the repository then navigate to folder by using cmdlet `cd  GithubAction-Terraform-Azure`
11. Create a folder with **terraform** name inside the `GithubAction-Terraform-Azure` folder
12. Save your `terraform.tf` file in terraform folder
13. Add the `terraform` folder to the Git repository using the following commands:

```
       git status  
        git add .
```

11. update the file using git commit command

```
     git commit -m "terraform"
     git push <git repository url>
```

12.Once push the code to the repository, the deployment will start automatically based on the actions, and the resources will be deployed in Azure.

[image]

Reference: [Deploy Terraform using GitHub Actions to Azure](https://thomasthornton.cloud/2021/03/19/deploy-terraform-using-github-actions-into-azure/)

Comment: I want to write terraform code for auto deployment of Git in azure. Not deploying terraform into azure. So, I need to connect Git and Azure first, Like If I make any changes in Git it should reflect in azure. Instead of doing this manually I want to write terraform code for the same. I need purely a terraform code for the above process.

Comment: Like I need the terraform code to connect GitHub and Azure.

Comment: Once You commit the terraform code to Github, it will deploy automatically by using Service principal, no need to create a connection in Terraform code again. You can provision any resources as per your requirements.

Comment: You can't a authenticate Github from Terraform.Git is repository for storing the content, for auto deployment, you have to use Github Action. Its not possible through Terraform code without Github action Or Devops.